# How can to show 3 object records based on last modified date

Tags: visualforce, wrapper-class

I have 3 objects Action, Decision, Issue. currently My list view showing 3 objects records one by one. First all Action records, next all Decision records , last all issue records. I want to show all the 3 object records based on last modified date. How can i do this..?

Page:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="searchTable4" value="{!wrapperlist}" var="wr">
                    <apex:column headervalue="Action">
                        <apex:outputLink target="_top"  value="/apex/ADI_Page?id={!wr.recId}">Edit</apex:outputLink>                                                                 
                    </apex:column> 
                    <apex:column headervalue="Name">
                        <apex:outputLink target="_top"  value="/{!wr.recId}">{!wr.name}</apex:outputLink>                                                                 
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!wr.OperationalArea}" headerValue="Operational Area"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!wr.Project}" headerValue="Project"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!wr.BusinessUnit}" headerValue="Business Unit"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!wr.Status}" headerValue="Status"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!wr.DueDateorRequestResolutiondate}" headerValue="Due Date / Request Resolution Date"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!wr.AssignToorOwner}" headerValue="AssignTo/Owner"/>
                    <apex:column id="descid" headervalue="Description"  >
                        <apex:outputtext id="desc">{!if(len(wr.description)<=50,LEFT(wr.description,50),RPAD(LEFT(wr.description,50),54,'...'))} </apex:outputtext>
                    </apex:column>
                    <!-- <apex:column value="{!wr.hasAttachment}" headerValue="Attachment"/>-->
                    <apex:column headervalue="Attachment">
                          <apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.paperclip}" width="20" height="15" rendered="{!wr.hasAttachment}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!wr.assignedDate}" headerValue="Assigned Date"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!wr.escalatedTo}" headerValue="Escalated To"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Controller :

```
public void combineobjects()
    {
        wrapperlist  = new list<wrapper>();
        for(ADI_Action__c adi : [Select id,name,RecordType.Name,Project__r.Name,Business_Unit__c,Status__c,Due_Date__c,Assigned_To__c,Assigned_To__r.Name,Action_Description__c,Has_Attachment__c,Assigned_Date__c,Escalate_To__r.Name from ADI_Action__c order by LastModifiedDate desc limit 300])
        {
            wrapper wr = new wrapper(adi.name,adi.RecordType.Name,adi.Project__r.Name,adi.Business_Unit__c,adi.Status__c,adi.Due_Date__c,adi.Assigned_To__r.Name,adi.id,adi.Action_Description__c,adi.Has_Attachment__c,adi.Assigned_Date__c,adi.Escalate_To__r.Name);
            wrapperlist.add(wr);
        }
        for(ADI_Decision__c adi : [Select id,name,RecordType.Name,Project__r.Name,Business_Unit__c,Status__c,Decision_Owner__c,Decision_Owner__r.Name,Decision_Description__c,Has_Attachment__c,Assigned_Date__c from ADI_Decision__c order by LastModifiedDate desc limit 300])
        {
            wrapper wr = new wrapper(adi.name,adi.RecordType.Name,adi.Project__r.Name,adi.Business_Unit__c,adi.Status__c,adi.Assigned_Date__c,adi.Decision_Owner__r.Name,adi.id,adi.Decision_Description__c,adi.Has_Attachment__c,adi.Assigned_Date__c,'');
            wrapperlist.add(wr);
        }

        for(ADI_Issue__c adi : [Select id,name,RecordType.Name,Project__r.Name,Business_Unit__c,Status__c,Requested_Resolution_Date__c,Assigned_To__c,Assigned_To__r.Name,Issue_Description__c,Has_Attachment__c,Assigned_Date__c,Escalate_To__r.Name from ADI_Issue__c order by LastModifiedDate desc limit 300])
        {
            wrapper wr = new wrapper(adi.name,adi.RecordType.Name,adi.Project__r.Name,adi.Business_Unit__c,adi.Status__c,adi.Requested_Resolution_Date__c,adi.Assigned_To__r.Name,adi.id,adi.Issue_Description__c,adi.Has_Attachment__c,adi.Assigned_Date__c,adi.Escalate_To__r.Name);
            wrapperlist.add(wr);
        }
    }

public class wrapper
    {
        public string name {get;set;}
        public string OperationalArea {get;set;}
        public string Project {get;set;}
        public string BusinessUnit {get;set;}
        public string Status {get;set;}
        public string DueDateorRequestResolutiondate {get;set;}
        public string AssignToorOwner {get;set;}
        public string recid {get;set;}
        public string description {get;set;}
        public boolean hasAttachment {get;set;}
        public string assignedDate {get;set;}
        public string relatedItems {get;set;}
        public string escalatedTo {get;set;}

        public wrapper(string name,String opera,string project,string bu,string status,Date ddrrd,string ato,string id,string description,boolean hasAttachment,Date assignedDate,string escalatedTo)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.OperationalArea = opera;
            this.Project = project;
            this.businessunit = bu;
            this.Status = status;
            if(ddrrd != null)
            this.DueDateorRequestResolutiondate = string.valueof(ddrrd);
            this.AssignToorOwner = ato;
            this.recid = id;
            this.description=description;
            this.hasAttachment=hasAttachment;
            if(assignedDate != null)
            this.assignedDate=string.valueof(assignedDate);
            this.escalatedTo=escalatedTo;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your wrapper class implement [Comparable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm):

```
public class Wrapper implements Comparable {
    ...
    private Datetime lastModifiedDate;
    Wrapper(ADI_Action__c sob) {
        ...
        lastModifiedDate = sob.LastModifiedDate;
    }
    Wrapper(ADI_Decision__c sob) {
        ...
        lastModifiedDate = sob.LastModifiedDate;
    }
    Wrapper(ADI_Issue__c sob) {
        ...
        lastModifiedDate = sob.LastModifiedDate;
    }
    public Integer compareTo(Object that) {
        Datetime d1 = lastModifiedDate;
        Datetime d2 = ((Wrapper) that).lastModifiedDate;
        if (d1 > d2) return -1;
        else if (d1 < d2) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and then just sort the list:

```
wrapperlist.sort();
```

which will cause the Comparable logic to be used.

Note in the Wrapper above I'm suggesting you add 3 constructors, one for each SObject type, and assign the fields in the constructors as that is probably a better place to do that work.

If you want the opposite sort order, swap the 1 and -1 in the `compareTo` method.